# Cant apply my own styles to my Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask

Creating a flask web app, and I am trying to change the styles on my navbar. Using a separate style sheet or putting them in the html file both havent worked, the only way it will change is if i put it directly in the `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #005194;">`. Any help with this would be appreciated, I have tried defining the navbar as .navbar.navbar-brand and as .navbar-brand.
My base.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block navbar %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #005194;">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">
                    Login Example
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}">
                    Dashboard
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

My stylesheet

```
.navbar.navbar-brand {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret_key'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and my index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.